# PHP dynamically add new column and value in existing Query

Tags: php, mysql

My application performs INSERT queries like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`) VALUES ('oneVal', 'twoVal', 'threeVal')
```

Now I want to rebuild my application so it will ALWAYS SELECT, INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE with a specific id.
Let's say the unique id is called: **companyId**

I don't want to rewrite all my queries manually, so I am trying to write a function that rewrites the existing SQL queries with PHP so it will include the **companyId** inside the query.

Desired outcome if companyId would be '1' (companyId IS NOT ALWAYS '1'!):

```
INSERT INTO table (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `companyId`) VALUES ('oneVal', 'twoVal', 'threeVal', '1')
```

My question(s) is/are:

1. Is there a way in PHP so I can dynamically rewrite the query so
   it would include the `companyId` column and the matching id value?
2. Is there a better way to do this? Like some trick setting MySQL
   server to ALWAYS use an extra value (in this case **companyId='1'**
   ?

I've tried option (1) by searching for the string

> ) VALUES

Once I found that string, I add `companyId` before the ).
Now get to the end of the query, get the most right ) and add the value before that.

But is this for a generic case? I think there might be a better way to solve this.

Thanks in advance community!

**EDIT 1 with more clarification**
Currently I've already built a function that modifies my **SELECT** statements.
Function code:

```
//If current query = SELECT query
if (containsString($sql, 'select')) {
    //Check if contains WHERE
    if (containsString($sql, 'where')) {
        //Yes
        //Add companyId after WHERE
        $sql = substr_replace($sql, '(companyId=?) AND ',  strpos($sql, 'WHERE') + 6, 0);
        //Explanation:
        //SELECT * FROM table WHERE deleted='No'; becomes -->
        //SELECT * FROM table WHERE (companyId=?) AND deleted='No';
    }else{
        //No
        //Get table , and after that INSERT WHERE companyId=?
        $tableName = explode(' from ', strtolower($sql))[1]; //Get part AFTER 'from'
        //First word after $tableName = tablename
        $tableName = explode(' ', $tableName)[0]; //First word after 'from' = tablename
        $sql = substr_replace($sql, 'WHERE (companyId=?) ',  strpos($sql, $tableName) + strlen($tableName) + 1, 0);
        //Explanation:
        //SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id; becomes -->
        //SELECT * FROM table WHERE (companyId=?) ORDER BY id;
    }
}
```

So this code dynamically adds an extra condition to the query statement.
This is also easily possible with **DELETE** and **UPDATE** statements (same as SELECT)
But Iam trying to come up with something like this for **INSERT INTO** queries.
How can I modify the original query using the new companyId?

Comment: Unless I misunderstand the meaning of 'add new column', this kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Comment: Insert a new column in the Mysql Table and assign it the default value of 1

Comment: @Strawberry Imagine I have one big database which is used by 10 companies. The data in the database tables needs to be split by companyId. Iam searching for an easy way to apply this structure without changing too much of my existing queries. Right now all my queries works without an companyId. But I want to add the companyId in all my SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE queries so the application would perform ONLY on the data of 'companyId'.
Let me know if there is something that is not clear.

Comment: @user1309690 Every company has its unique companyId.

Comment: So this is about adding rows, not columns !?!

Comment: @Strawberry yes the query INSERT INTO is about adding rows indeed. But my questions is about adding an extra COLUMN inside the already existing sql query. So "INSERT INTO table (`col1`) VALUES ('test')" needs to add 1 extra column in the QUERY "INSERT INTO table (`col1`, `companyId`) VALUES ('test', '1')"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess If you have an associative array with the column names and values then you easily can make it more dynamic for future also. Let's say you've an array of column names with value of it e.g

```
$data = ['col1'=>'val1','col2'=>'val2','col3'=>'val3','companyId'=>1];

$query = "INSERT INTO `yourtable` ( ".implode(' , ', array_keys($data)).") VALUES ('".implode("' , '", array_values($data))."')";
echo $query;
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/udt1i

Then you can do with `regex` replace way *globally* to add column and value to all of your 100 query.

```
<?php
$re = '/\) VALUES (.+?(?=\)))/m';
$str = 'INSERT INTO table (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`) VALUES (\'oneVal\', \'twoVal\', \'threeVal\')';
$subst = ',`col4`) VALUES $1 , \'1\'';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
?>
```

**DEMO**: https://3v4l.org/rOQDG

Comment: This might be a solution. However. My initial thoughts where to not rewrite an existing query. So I have maybe 100 "INSERT INTO " queries all over the place in my application. Right now I just need to add 1 col and value into ALL the "INSERT INTO" queries. So I wanted to write the query as I stated in my Question and then have some function in PHP that adds 1 col and value into the existing query.
However, your solution requires me to rewrite all my current INSERT INTO queries. Could be a solution, but I'm curious if there is another way.

Comment: @StanvanderAvoird I've edited my answer. Have a look again

Comment: @user:1138192 @user1138192 I have a question about your solution. This only works for the precise syntax: ") VALUES (" . But sometimes I write my queries with more spaces/new lines like so:
"INSERT INTO table (`col1`, `col2`) 
VALUES
('val1', 'val2')"
 
Your solution works perfectly for the precise syntax, but could you please adjust it a little bit so it would work with random spaces & enters? Would really appreciate!

Comment: I think I fixed it myself by adding a new line of code:
` $sql = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $sql);`
Which removes any extra spaces, tabs etc.

Comment: Removing multiple spaces with single space, that's a good way to fix that :)

Comment: An `m` pattern modifier is useless if the pattern doesn't contain start of line or end of line metacharacters (`^` or `$`). `m` does not affect a dot -- `s` does.  `m` does not mean "hey regex engine, my input string might contain newline characters, be on the lookout."